# How to compare two lists of String in Realm Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, realm, realm-list

I have the following Realm data structure:

```
class Pair {
    @objc dynamic var kanji: String? = nil
    let kana = List<String>()
}
```

I need to look up an entry in the Realm the `Pair.kana` property of which has the same elements. How do I achieve that (preferably using `NSPredicate`)?

Comment: So do you need to compare two `List<String>`s or a `List<String>` and an `Array<String>`? There's no need for an `NSPredicate` btw if you simply want to compare them for element-wise equality.

Comment: does order matter?  like ["b","a","c"] and ["c", "a", "b"]. would you say these equal or do not?

Comment: @DávidPásztor I need to look up an entry in the database which has the same elements. Two List<String>.

Comment: @Augie order does not matter.

Comment: I have updated my question accordingly, thanks for your remarks.

Comment: Realm lists of primitives can not be filtered with predicate.  We'll need a workout around that's not terribly slow. https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/5334

Comment: you could filter your results where pair.kana.count == comparing pair's count, but then you'd have to iterate the remaining matches, converting pair to array and then check for equality.  Not very performant for large collections.

Comment: another option would be to add property kanaAsString to your class, sort kana and then flatten to string and store in kanaAsString.  Then you could search for exact matches that way.